# How to convert a vector of enumerable strings into a vector of numbers?

Tags: r

How to convert the x below to into a vector like y?

```
x <- ["a", "b", "b", "c", ...]

y <- [1, 2, 2, 3, ...]
```

**UPDATE:**

I end up with:

```
levels(x) <- 1:length(levels(x))
```

Comment: If nothing else, use a hash table from the package "hash". set the characters as key and the numbers as the values and the go through each one, converting the key to the value.

Comment: This question appears to be only about data minapulation in R and thus belongs on StackOverflow (where it's been asked numerous times already). 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possibility, very similar than that of @Roman Lustrik, but just a little bit more automatic.

Say that

> x <- c("a", "b", "b", "c")

Then

```
   > x <- as.factor(x)
   > levels(x) <- 1:length(levels(x))
   > x <- as.numeric(x)
```

makes the job:

```
   > print(x)
   [1] 1 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Another programming question has sneaked...

Anyway, the faster way is

```
unclass(factor(x))
```

additionally one can add `levels(...)<-NULL` to remove the redundant attribute too (not much required inside a script).

Comment: nice, I didn't know "unclass"  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways of doing this. Here's one.

```
> (a <- as.factor(sample(letters[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE)))
    [1] d a e e e c b e b b c a d d d d c b c c b b e b e b c d c b
    Levels: a b c d e
> (levels(a) <- 1:5)
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5
> a <- as.numeric(a) # convert these factors into numbers
```

Comment: Lustrik: +1 ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
as.numeric(factor(c("d", "a", "b", "b", "c")))

[1] 4 1 2 2 3
```